# Easy fancybox close button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So I'm working with my site and I have installed [Easy FancyBox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/) I got the modal part working but when I clicked on the close button `#fancybutton-close`

```
   $.fancybox.close();
```

is not working though I put some alert and it fires it. So what I'm missing here?

Here is the link to my test site: http://vetclinic.dragonscalewebdev.com/courseswebinars/

P.S. I put the fancybox modal in the testimonial part of my page and I only put two pop up just for testing purposes.

Comment: Please give more details and some code and tell us what you'vetried so far

Comment: Please post some actual code to Stack Overflow. My guess is that since you have fancybox loading content the code that fires your call to $.fancybox.close() isn't being reached.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.close-modal').click(function(){
        window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
    });
});
```